# Retina Macbook and optimizing Windows 8 Resolution

Tags: mac, windows-8, boot-camp, macbook-pro-retina

What's the best way to optimize Windows 8 (operating system) resolution on a retina MacBook?

Text randomly appears too small, the wrong windows are the wrong size, etc.

Comment: "...the wrong windows are the wrong size, etc." -- Are the "right windows" the right size? :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the steps from Tony Schreiner in his [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tonyschr/windows-8-on-macbook-pro-with-retina-display):

> By default Boot Camp will configure Windows to use 144 DPI. This is a
> good default because it strikes a balance between making UI elements
> large enough to be usable, while still staying within the “supported”
> realm of mainstream Windows software. By this, what I mean is that up
> until recently (at least at Microsoft) it was a given to make sure
> applications worked well at 125% and 150% DPI scaling, but 200%
> scaling has been less tested and is also less likely to have icons and
> other art that natively scales to that setting.
>
> For reasonably advanced users **I recommend enabling “Use Windows XP
> style scaling” under the “Custom sizing options”. This prevents the OS
> from using the DWM to use bitmap stretching** on the application to make
> everything bigger at the expense of quality.
>
> For **Internet Explorer 10 I bump the zoom factor to 200% (192 DPI)** for
> most casual web surfing. This gives a very comfortable text size while
> eliminating wasted space. Text is incredibly sharp, well-defined, and
> readable. There is no longer any concern over respecting the font vs.
> respecting the pixel grid. Images look blurry in comparison, but
> unlike at ~120 DPI it’s an acceptable trade-off, and they don’t look
> worse than they would if I were running at a lower resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Using an MBPR mid 2012 on Bootcamp. I recommend you set DPI scaling to 100% from the Control Panel:

**Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Set a custom scaling level**
Then adjust your display resolution to a reasonable setting that would still render the screen legible, something to the neighborhood 1600xN-1680xN. Expect of course that the display will be a little blurry, but the aim here is to get to a sweet spot where you don't need a magnifying glass to recognize text.

Try to stay clear away from using a DPI scaling of 150%+...totally messes up UI elements in apps like PowerPoint and more.

Having said this, my personal preference is really at 125% scaling level with a resolution of 1980x1080p. Maybe a few tweaks to ClearType, and then color calibrated to a higher whitepoint (I like a bluish tinge, rather than to a yellowish hue) from the Control Panel as well. Nice, good compromise for me.